# Android OAUTH tokens storage

Tags: android, database, oauth, save

Where should the token be saved after they are retrieved from a OAuth flow? Is it better to save them in a local database on the phone, or am I missing a better way?

Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way is to save them to the shared preferences object where you retrieve them when you want to send a tweet etc. Like so:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,consumer.getTokenSecret());
edit.commit();
```